# Selenium python instagram follow button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, bots

This seems to not work to follow in  Instagram using selenium
There is no error produced still it is not following

```
follow = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Follow']")

ActionChains(webdriver).move_to_element(follow).click().perform()
```

Comment: Can you put post a small working piece of code with the webpage?

Comment: I figured it out thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work when I use the full xpath of the follow button and I removed the actionchains and used just the click()

```
follow = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button").click()
```